# Does $v^TAv = 0$, imply $Av = 0$ for $A$ be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, $v \in\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. if  $v^TAv = 0$, can we deduce that $Av = 0$ for $v \in\mathbb{R}^n$?

My try:

Since $A$ is a real positive semi-definite matrix we can write $A=B^TB$ for some matrix $B$. Then

$$0 = v^TAv = v^TB^TBv =(Bv)^TBv= \langle Bv,Bv\rangle \implies Bv =0\implies B^TBv =Av=0  $$

Comment: What have you tried? What theory do you know about matrices in general and symmetric PSD matrices in particular that seems like it might help? What's stopping you from applying that theory?

Comment: When you have an equation of the form $(\text{product of matrices/vectors}) = 0$ and you'd like to deduce that some factor equals 0, a good trick to try is to turn your given equation into something that looks like $\langle \text{some vector}, \text{same vector} \rangle = 0$. Then you can deduce that that vector equals 0. For example, if you had the equation $v^T B^T B v = 0$, then you could write the left hand side as $(Bv)^T(Bv) = \langle Bv, Bv \rangle$, whence you could conclude that $Bv = \vec 0$. Maybe you could turn $v^T Av$ into $v^T B^T B v$ somehow?

Comment: Have you tried $A=0$?

Comment: Hint: consider $(tu-v)^TA(tu-v)$ for an arbitrary vector $u$.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Even easier, just apply the Spectral Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

This is true even in infinite-dimensional inner product spaces. It can be proved by using basic properties of inner product. Sophisticated tools like spectral decomposition or existence of square root are not needed.

Suppose $A$ is a (weakly) positive operator and $\langle Av,v\rangle=0$. Then for any vector $u$,
$$
0\le\langle A(tu+v)\,,tu+v\rangle
=t^2\langle Au,u\rangle+
2t\operatorname{Re}\langle Av,u\rangle
$$
for all real numbers $t$. Therefore $\operatorname{Re}\langle Av,u\rangle$ is necessarily zero. In particular, when $u=Av$, we get $0=\operatorname{Re}\langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle Av,Av\rangle$. Hence $Av=0$.